# Windows 10: how to detect again the second monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows 10 on my desktop. This morning, I installed an old Samsung Syncmaster (that can show only up to 1680x1050 resolution) as my second monitor. The computer detected it and set it up correctly.

Now I've replaced it with a LG 2240 monitor, that can display up to 1920x1080. Windows works fine with both monitors, but when I get into Settings/Display and the "Advanced" section, the second monitor still shows up as "Syncmaster", and is at 1680x1050 resolution.

I changed it to 1920x1080 and it worked fine, but the name is still "Syncmaster", and when I it the "Detect" button, Windows says that it can't detect any new monitors.

How can I force Windows to detect the monitor as a new one?

(Forgot to add: both monitors have only VGA connections. I plug them into my PC with a DVI-D to VGA adapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I should have made a bit more of an effort on my own before asking. Inspired by @harrymc 's answer above, I went to Configuration / Devices... and there they were, all the devices plugged into the PC, including "Syncmaster".

I didn't have to edit the registry or do anything else: just right-click on "Syncmaster", hit "Remove" and reboot. Windows now detects correctly my new monitor.

Answer (score 1):

One
[Dell article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/audhs1/how12265/how-to-remove-ghost-or-non-attached-monitors-showing-in-windows-display-settings?lang=en)
recommends the following method:

- Right-click and remove your excess monitor from
  *Devices and Printers* in Control Panel
- Right-click and uninstall any Generic PnP monitor(s) appearing in Device Manager
- Reboot.

If this does not help, a much upvoted
[answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-reset-external-monitors-settings/b3a53cef-e54f-4410-b09e-6846fa297a3f)
contains this procedure:

- Run `regedit`
- Locate these three registry keys, right-click each one and select Delete:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors
  ```
- Reboot.

I suggest before starting to create a System Restore point in order to be able
to go back to the current state.